# I want to generate a UI which allows me to select and deselect my Test Cases and Run the selected test cases (Test Developer)

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've plenty of test cases, say 100. when i want to run my regression/smoke tests i can do that by dividing those in groups and running the testng.xml file..           but my wish is to create a UI which have the test case names,browsers.when i want to run 2-3 test cases, i'll just run select the test cases and browsers and then click on 'Run'(A button in my UI).    so it'll interact with testng.xml and then send values to it. so indirectly i want to edit the testng.xml file and then run the testsuite. Anyone can help me out in this COntext or give me links of some online tutorial or anything from which i can get help ?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Eclipse](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html), [Cucumber](http://www.seleniumframework.com/cucumber-jvm-3/cucumber-jvm-and-selenium/) and [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) to do this.

Comment: It is easier to innovate than to create.  I hate it when I have to be creative. (smile)